# Does minimizing number of attribute selected improve the performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server script, I join one table to a big table. Does number of items selected matter in SQL performance?

My two option are:

```
SELECT
    tu.Time,
    tu.Machine_id,             
    AVG(tu.cpu_rate) AS cpu_usage,      
    AVG(tu.canonical_memory_usage) AS memory_usage,
    AVG(tu.cpu_rate) / [dbo].[FnGetCpuInfoWithfailMachineId](tu.machine_id, tu.sampling_start_time) AS cpu_utilization,
    AVG(tu.canonical_memory_usage) / dbo.[FnGetMemoryInfoWithfailMachineId](tu.machine_id, tu.sampling_start_time) AS memory_utilization,
    [dbo].[FnGetCpuRequestTotalWithfailMachineId](tu.machine_id, tu.sampling_start_time) AS cpu_request_total,
    [dbo].[FnGetMemoryRequestTotalWithfailMachineId](tu.machine_id, tu.sampling_start_time) AS memory_request_total,
    [dbo].[FnGetPerformanceInfoWithfailMachineId](tu.machine_id, tu.sampling_start_time, AVG(tu.cycles_per_instruction)) AS performance
FROM
    [dbo].[failure_host_machine_events] AS h 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Failed_hosts_task_usage] AS tu ON h.machine_id = tu.machine_id

group by tu.machine_id, tu.time
```

OR

```
SELECT
    tu.Time,
    tu.Machine_id,
    [dbo].[FnGetPerformanceInfoWithfailMachineId](tu.machine_id, tu.sampling_start_time, AVG(tu.cycles_per_instruction)) AS performance
FROM
    [dbo].[failure_host_machine_events] AS h 
INNER JOIN
    [dbo].[Failed_hosts_task_usage] AS tu ON h.machine_id = tu.machine_id
group by tu.machine_id, tu.time
```

The very big table is `[dbo].[Failed_hosts_task_usage]`. Any ideas if these 2 scripts are different in performance and time consumption? Or since I join these 2 tables it doesn't matter how many attributes I select

Comment: I'm not even sure that either of these two queries would run, because you are selecting the average of several columns over the entire table along with individual record-level columns.  But as for your question, I might expect selecting fewer columns to outperform more columns on some level.  But you can just test both and see which one is faster.

Comment: Thank you @TimBiegeleisen. It the average column over 'function' not table

Comment: No...it's an average of a column over the entire table.  So it does make sense to select anything other than other aggregates.

Comment: I will test both of them, in where condition, I will choose one machine_id

Comment: If both queries have the same query plan (again, assuming that either one actually runs), then the only remaining issue is how much data is being returned.  More columns means more data, which in turn implies greater overhead when sending this data across a network.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, there is a difference. Two main reasons:

1. Less data to pass from server to client, resulting in less network utilization etc.
2. Potentially less expensive query plan.

Let me elaborate on the second point... Let's say you have a structure like this:

```
-- Create a test table...

CREATE TABLE T (
    ID int IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
    NAME nvarchar(255),
    FOO int
);

CREATE INDEX THE_INDEX ON T(NAME);

-- Fill it with some data...

WITH DIGIT(N) AS (
    SELECT 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 2
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 3
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 4
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 6
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 7
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 8
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9
),
NUMBER(N) AS (
    SELECT
        D4.N * 10000 + D3.N * 1000 + D2.N * 100 + D1.N * 10 + D0.N NUMBER
    FROM
        DIGIT D0
        CROSS JOIN DIGIT D1
        CROSS JOIN DIGIT D2
        CROSS JOIN DIGIT D3
        CROSS JOIN DIGIT D4
)
INSERT INTO T(NAME, FOO)
SELECT N, N FROM NUMBER;
```

Now, consider the execution plan difference between two almost identical queries:

```
SELECT ID, NAME FROM T WHERE NAME = '50000';
SELECT * FROM T WHERE NAME = '50000';
```

[image]

Note how the second query does essentially twice the work, just because FOO is present in the SELECT list! The reason is that FOO is not [covered](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/clustering/index-only-scan-covering-index) by THE_INDEX, so for each found row, the database has to do an additional lookup just to retrieve the FOO. *(On the other hand, ID is PK and therefore automatically included in THE_INDEX.)*

Conclusion: strive to include *only* the attributes you actually need in the SELECT list.

---

Whether any of this brings meaningful improvements in your *specific* case is another matter... the only reliable way to tell is to **measure** on representative amount of data.

Comment: thank you @Branko , great concept. Assume both queries will  do an additional lookup just to retrieve other attributes, which are not indexes such attr `X1`, and `X2`.                                                                            in your example. `'SELECT ID, NAME, X1, X2 FROM T WHERE NAME = '50000';`
`SELECT * FROM T WHERE NAME = '50000';` What is different, since both will do an additional lookup

Answer (score 1):

Your queries are not syntactically correct, because they should have a `group by`.  But I still think I understand the question.

In general, the performance of a query is dominated by accessing the data, doing the joins and the aggregations.  As a general rule, the number of attributes has relatively little impact on performance.  That is why much of the effort for performance optimization centers on choosing appropriate join and group by algorithms.

That said, there are circumstances where what is selected does have an impact.  For instance:

- `count(distinct)` is more expensive than other aggregations (as is `for xml path`).
- String operations -- particularly on long strings -- can be expensive.
- Some complex expressions can take time.  This is especially true of some user-defined functions.
- Any really big fields can have an effect on performance.

And there are no doubt other situations as well.  But in your case, the `join` and `group by` are probably going to dominate the performance and you should focus efforts on making those faster (if you care about performance).

Comment: Thank you @Gordon. I forget to add the group by in this post. Seems in my case, the number of attributes is not the big issues. However, aggregations might affect the performance at some level. .

Comment: Assume second query take 20 hours, how much first one take. I run second one, it reach up to 86% in 10 minutes in estimated query progress. then it get settled at same 86% for 4 hours.